# How do I disable Anon Auth in IIS 8 for Sharepoint 2013 without losing functionality?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, iis

Setup:
2012 Server with IIS 8.5 hosting Sharepoint 2013 with the SP database hosted on a separate 2012 Server.

Whenever I disable Anonymous Authentication for the website in IIS, my SP site loses functionality to save properties/meta data for documents (i.e., Title, Security Attributes, other customized column data, etc.).

However, when I enable it I am able to return functionality to the site when uploading documents or modifying their properties.

Our security team is mandating that we disable this setting because its a CAT 1 STIG and needs to be closed.

I have scoured the interwebs looking for anything that states this setting is a must for Sharepoint 2013, but having much difficulty.

I am hoping that someone out there can provide some insight knowledge so I can justify this setting needing to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You cant disable it as this functionality required for the claims based authentication. As you mentioned that when you disable it then you will lost the functionality.

> The WCF runtime requires anonymous authentication for claims-based web
>   applications.

[SharePoint - Claims-based web applications require anonymous authentication in IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2850515/sharepoint-claims-based-web-applications-require-anonymous-authenticat)

Also read this blog, which help you understand more.

[Anonymous Authentication always on in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/02/anonymous-authentication-always-on-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: The link to "SharePoint - Claims-based web applications require anonymous authentication in IIS" no longer valid. For the 2nd link, the author seems not understand why MS disable it?